# batch file opening endless CMDs

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file with the following codes.
when it finishes opening the other batch files.. an endless loop of opening CMDs pops out.

```
start bat1.bat
TIMEOUT 5
start bat2.bat
TIMEOUT 5
start bat3.bat
TIMEOUT 5
start bat4.bat
TIMEOUT 5
start bat5.bat
TIMEOUT 5
end
```

how can I terminate the main batch file after calling the other batch files?

Comment: There is no loop present in the code you have posted. (Also, `end` isn't a batch command.) Once a batch script runs out of code to run, it will terminate naturally.

Comment: but it keeps opening endless CMDs after calling the last batch file.

Comment: Is your main batch file named `start.bat` or `start.cmd` or `timeout.bat` etc. which could execute your script over and over?

Comment: no.. it's `main.bat`

Comment: What happens when you use the correct command, `Call`, instead of `start`, get rid of all the unnecessary `TIMEOUT` commands and also remove `end` from the last line?

Comment: I found my error.. it's on the last one.. when I try to open chrome using 

`start chrome` it opens an endless CMDs'' how can I open chrome after all bat files have been called?

Comment: If you want us to help you with lines in your batch script, it would be prudent to add those lines to the script in your question.

Comment: As you do not seem to be new here you should know that a good question is important so people can help you. Please provide further information regarding the content of `main.bat` and `bat1.bat` - `bat5.bat` unless you are sure that they are not connected to the problem whatsoever.